# Compatibility issues with sql server 2008 data center edition on windows 8

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-8

I am trying to install Sql Server 2008 R2 Data Center Edition on Windows 8 but I am getting this message: "This program has compatibility issues" Is it save to install it anyway? Maybe someone has tried and it worked well.

What is the version that should be installing?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'safe'? I'd also hope you're not planning on running a production database (and if you're running data center edition, you'd probably want to be spending the money($60K a processor!) on either a production, or a test system and not a dev's personal system) on a 'workstation'/'consumer' grade OS. Go get yourself a copy of SQL server express.

Comment: "Get"? It _comes_ with Visual Studio. Try your Visual Studio install again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft says you're in good shape, if and only if you apply service pack 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2681562).

Why are you installing this in a desktop OS though?